# how to migrate my Q from unix.stackexchange.com to ubuntu.com?

Tags: discussion, migration

I have [this Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147368/ubuntu-13-10-has-suddenly-failed-to-boot) in unix.stackexchange.com that I feel should be migrated to askubuntu.com as it hasn't got much view. How to do that please?

Comment: Note that while AU has more eyes, it also has more questions. Questions [on U&L](http://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/213319/average-views-per-question-by-month) get more views in their first few months than [on AU](http://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/213319/average-views-per-question-by-month)!

Answer (score 1):

Asking in the chat room or leaving a comment on your question to a moderator are 2 ways to accomplish this. I've migrated your question to Ask Ubuntu as you've requested.

Comment: Thanks a lot slm!

Comment: The migration was rejected because it's about an Ubuntu version that's no longer supported.